Flutter hive package - hiveerror: this object is currently not in a box
For user of my app the following error with the hive package occured

"hiveerror: this object is currently not in a box."

when trying to save a hivetype object via save() method. The error has never occured in the app for any other user, and no documentation exists on the error. I would be grateful for any general context on what triggers this error.
